# Add border to top of image using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, border

I have an image 100x40 and I want to add a border to the top of the image 10 pixels high.

I've found

```
convert source.jpg -border 0x10 out.jpg
```

but this adds a border to the top and bottom. Is there anyway to add it to only the top?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `-splice`:

`convert source.jpg -splice 0x10 out.jpg`

If you want to add the border only *at the bottom*, use `-gravity` as well:
`convert source.jpg -gravity south -splice 0x10 out.jpg`

Note that the border will be transparent, unless you use `-background`, too.

See also [Cutting and Bordering](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/) for more examples.

Answer (score 5):

Use `-extent` instead:

```
convert source.jpg -gravity south -extent 100x50 out.jpg
```

`-gravity` tell it which direction to move the original image.

Comment: I should have said, I'm doing this to a batch of images which all have different sizes so I wouldn't be able to know what dimensions to pass to the -extent option. Having said that, it's a very useful option to know about.

Comment: [Shay Maor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6805724/shay-maor) adds the following: you can get width and height using `magick convert "{0}" -format "%wx%h" info` where {0} is the absolute file path. (Redirected from Review).

Answer (score 2):

Tested as of 6.9.11, the default background is now white, not transparent, at least for PNG input/output.

To get a transparent background you need something like:

```
convert source.png -gravity north -background transparent -splice 0x10 out.png
```

`north` adds on top, `south` on bottom.

Also note that `-background` has to come before `-splice`.

Demo JPG input:

```
wget -O chick.jpg https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Hühnerküken_02.jpg/800px-Hühnerküken_02.jpg
```

[image]

Default color conversion (white border on top):

```
convert chick.jpg -gravity north -splice 0x100 chick-default.jpg
```

[image]

Black border on top with `north`:

```
convert chick.jpg -gravity north -background black -splice 0x100 chick-black.jpg
```

[image]

Black border on bottom with `south`:

```
convert chick.jpg -gravity south -background black -splice 0x100 chick-black-south.jpg
```

[image]

Add border both on top and bottom with a double splice:

```
convert chick.jpg -background black -gravity south -splice 0x100 \
  -gravity north -splice 0x100 chick-black-north-south.jpg
```

[image]

Add 100px border all around image instead with `-border` as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/819482/how-to-add-a-border-using-imagemagick

```
convert -bordercolor black -border 100 chick.jpg chick-around.jpg
```

[image]